# Delay with Twilio Flex Web Chat

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I have a problem with the chat window of Twilio WebChat. When I close the chat and I open another page of the website, the chat opens again. I fixed it with the FlexWebChat Action of MinimizeChat when the Local Storage variable isEntryPointExpanded is false.

First, I save in a variable if the chat is open or closed

```js
    Twilio.FlexWebChat.Actions.on("beforeToggleChatVisibility", (payload) => {
        let item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('twilio-flex-cf')); 
        localStorage.setItem('my-state', !item.flex.session.isEntryPointExpanded)
    });
```

And after the webchat.init() I check if its open or closed and minimize it or no.

```js
        let myState = localStorage.getItem('my-state')
        if (myState === 'false') { 
            Twilio.FlexWebChat.Actions.invokeAction('MinimizeChat')
        }
```

The problem is that the variable isEntryPointExpanded takes some tenth of a second to update when I expand/close the chat, and then sometimes the variable where I kept if the chat is open or not, has a wrong value.

Comment: Can you share the code you're talking about here? And the error you are getting?

Comment: I have added some more information, thank you

Comment: Please note that this is known issue which we are tracking internally. In the meantime, could you try this gist? https://gist.github.com/rbeatie/7e0d718c19d1559a6015b4bff289049f Thanks!